# Email function is not sending : Hosting server godaddy

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm created email function in php, my files and all hosting is godaddy.
when ever i'm submitting my form mail is not sent it is going to if condition inside showing error message --- mail not sent successfully!.please some one help me..
my Php function code is blow:

```
<?php
include("/home/mu3c3ezzh1cs/public_html/mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name         = $_POST['name'];
  $email        = $_POST['email'];
  $mobile       = $_POST['phone'];
  $location     = $_POST['location'];
  $decs         = $_POST['desc'];
  $contact_name ="Please check the Requirement";
  $message = "";
  $subject_thankyou = "Enquiry Acknowledgement from abc.";
  $message_thankyou = "<p>Dear ".$name.",</p><p>We just received your enquiry. We will get back to you as soon as possible. Thank you for the interest shown on .</p><p>Best Regards<br /> abc<br/> Web :<a href='http://abc.in'>www.abc.in</a></p>";
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
  $mail->SMTPAuth  = true;  // authentication enabled
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Host     = "hostname";/*Specify main and backup SMTP servers*/
  $mail->Port     = 465;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;/*Enable SMTP authentication*/
  $mail->Username = "username";/*SMTP username*/
  $mail->Password = "password";/*SMTP password*/
  $mail->setFrom('info@abd.com', 'abc');
  $mail->addAddress($email , $name);
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = $subject_thankyou;
  $mail->Body    = $message_thankyou;
  $mail->AltBody = $subject_thankyou;
  $mail->send();
  $subject ='Enquiry for abc'; 

  $email_header ='<html style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: -webkit-auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 575px; line-height: 18px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    <head>
                      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                  </head>
                  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000"  style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: -webkit-auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); max-width: 575px; line-height: 18px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                  <table style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;background:#EFEDED;padding:0 0 10px 0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EFEDED" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                  <table width="96%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"border="0">
                  <tbody>              
                  <tr>
                  <td style="border-top:5px solid #1e96d3;background:#fff;margin:0; padding:20px; border-spacing:0px;">';

  $email_footer = '</td>
                    </tr>               
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                    </tr>              
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </body>
                    </html>';

    $body = $email_header.
        '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
              <td style="margin:0; padding:0px 0px 15px 0px; border-spacing:0px;">
              <p style="font-size:14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0px; padding: 0.4em; text-align: left;">
              '.$subject.'
              </p>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td style="margin:0; padding:0px 0px 15px 0px; border-spacing:0px;">
              <p style="color:#000; font-size:13px; margin:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;">
              <strong>
              '.$contact_name.',
              </strong>
              <br>
              </p>
              </td>
              </tr>                     
              <tr>
              <td style="margin:0; padding:0 0 5px 0;">
              <p style="font-size:13px; background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0px; padding: 0.4em; text-align: left;">
              Details:
              </p>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td style="margin:0; padding:0px 0px 15px 0px; border-spacing:0px;">
              <table style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; margin-top:10px; width:100%">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td style="width:120px; padding:4px 0;">
              Name
              </td>  
              <td style="padding-right:10px;">
              :
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:normal;">
              '.$name.'
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td style="padding:4px 0;">
              Phone Number
              </td>
              <td>
              :
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:normal;">
              '.$mobile.'
              </td>
              </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="padding:4px 0;">
              Email
              </td>
              <td>
              :
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:normal;">
              '.$email.'
              </td>
              </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="padding:4px 0;">
              Location
              </td>
              <td>
              :
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:normal;">
              '.$location.'
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td style="padding:4px 0;">
              Description
              </td>
              <td>
              :
              </td>
              <td style="font-weight:normal;">
              '.$decs.'
              </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
              </td>
              </tr>
              </table>'
              .$email_footer;
    $message .= $body;
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure= false;  
    $mail->Host     = "hostname";
    $mail->Port     = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;/*Enable SMTP authentication*/
    $mail->Username = "username";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->setFrom('info@abc.com', $name);
    $mail->addAddress('abc@gmail.com' , 'abc');
    $mail->isHTML(true);

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
            ?>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                   window.alert("mail not sent successfully!");
                  // window.location.href="thanks.php";
                </script>
                 <?php
          }
           else{
         ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
               window.location.href="thanks.php";
            </script>
             <?php
       }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you could get the error reason [directly from PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#read-the-smtp-transcript) by setting the `SMTPDebug` option to 1?

Comment: It's working now i'm getting mail .. in mail it is showing like ---Warning! Unverified sender.
We could not verify that the email was actually from abc@gmail.com. Be cautious when opening any links/ attachments, if any, in this email

Comment: Sounds like it didn't go through Gmail's servers, but was sent from GoDaddy's own SMTP servers directly to the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem: **you're on GoDaddy**.

GoDaddy doesn't allow you to send through any mail servers other than their own (usually using the mail server at `relay.secureserver.net`). Switching to that solves one problem, but creates another: You can't send *from* a gmail address unless you're sending through a gmail server; it's not permitted by their SPF rules, and your messages will not contain gmail's DKIM signature. That means your messages are effectively forgeries, which is why you're seeing such warnings - frankly I'm surprised they arrive at all.

So there are two solutions:

1. Don't send from a gmail address when you're not using gmail servers; send from a domain that allows sending from GoDaddy's servers (i.e. your own domain).
2. Don't use GoDaddy; use a different hosting provider that does not block outbound SMTP.

All of this is covered in the PHPMailer docs.

Separately from this, you're using a **very** old version of PHPMailer that's buggy and vulnerable, so I suggest you [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and base your code on the examples provided.